# Overridden equals and hashCode does not work on custom Object;

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have an below object

```
class CustomObj{
    private String name;
    private String dept;

   public String getName(){
     return this.name;
   }

   public String getDept(){
     return this.dept;
   }

   private CustomObj(){
   }

   private CustomObj(CustomObjBuilder builder){
     this.name = builder.name;
     this.dept= builder.dept;
  }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object o) {

      if (o == this) return true;
      if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

      CustomObj that = (CustomObj) o;

      return that.name.equals(name) &&
            that.dept.equals(dept);
    }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
     int result = 31;
     result = 31 * result + name.hashCode();
     result = 31 * result + dept.hashCode();
     return result;
   }

  public static class CustomObjBuilder{
     private String name;
     private  String dept;


     public CustomObjBuilder(String name, String dept){
        this.name = name;
        this.dept = dept;
     }

     public CustomObjBuilder setName(String name){
       this.name = name;
       return this;
     }

     public CustomObjBuilder setDept(String dept){
      this.dept = dept;
      return this;
     }

     public CustomObj build(){
            return new CustomObj(this);
    }
}
 }
```

and class that uses above

```
class XYZ{
   Set<CustomObj> obj = new HashSet<CustomObj>();

   public void process(String a, String b){
       CustomObj o = new CustomObj.CustomObjBuilder(a,b).build();
       if(!obj.contains(o)){
        obj.add(o);
       } 
   }
}
```

And a test class

```
class TestXYX{

@Test
public void test(){
 XYZ xyz = new XYZ();
 xyz.process("TEST","TESTABC");
 xyz.process("TEST","TESTABC");
}
}
```

Beacuse I have overrideen hascode and equals, both the above are equal and when process is called second time, the control should not go into `if(!obj.contains(o))` second time and size of the set should be 1. But when i run the test  `obj.add(o);` is called two times. But the values of both this object and that objec inside equals methods are same, but

```
that.name.equals(name) && that.dept.equals(dept)
```

inside CustomObj returns false. Can someone please help me understand why?

Comment: Your code works fine. if(!obj.contains(o)) fails second time.

Comment: the code is working fine. what made to you think the control went inside if?

Answer (score -1):

The code is fine. To verify add an `sysout` to check `Set` size:

```
class XYZ {
    Set<CustomObj> obj = new HashSet<CustomObj>();

    public void process(String a, String b) {
        CustomObj o = new CustomObj.CustomObjBuilder(a, b).build();
        if (!obj.contains(o)) {         // Fails second time for your use case.
            obj.add(o);
        }
        System.out.println(obj.size());  // This is 1 in your use case.
    }
}
```